# Postgres unique index for a date on a date time field

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, postgresql-9.4, unique-index

I have a table `event_logs` with two columns of interest for which I would like to create an index.  The problem is one of the columns is a datetime field, which is fine for 99% of the things we use it for as it stores both the date and time for a given event.

However I would like to create a unique index which would make it impossible to create two events on the same date (not datetime, but just the date) with the same person.

- quiz_master_id (integer)
- start_at (datetime)

Is it even possible to do such a think to create such a unique index for a given date instead of datetime? Or is there another similar method to deal with this in Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just want an index on an expression:

```
create unique index idx_eventlogs_startatdate
    on event_logs(date_trunc('day', start_at))
```